# Badge for accepting/rejecting edits?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an incentive for approving/rejecting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77042/add-an-incentive-for-approving-rejecting-edits)

I couldn't find a similar suggestions, therefore I suggest a badge for users who have reviewed (accepted or rejected) 1000 edit suggestions.

The name and the threshold can be discussed ;)